# Angular 2 - Component stops rendering after first directive was rendered

Tags: templates, angular

I have built a small application to play some sounds. I want to use a few directives together in my root-components' template.

This is my app.component.ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Track} from './track'
import {AudioControls} from './audio-controls.component';
import {TrackDisplay} from './track-display.component';
import {StreamingService} from './streaming.service'
import {DataProvider} from './data-provider.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [StreamingService, DataProvider],
    directives: [TrackDisplay, AudioControls],
    template:`
      <span>Teststring 1</span>
      <audio-controls>
      <span>Teststring 2</span>
      <track-display>
    `
})



export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

I added providers and directives properly, and the directives are both working, if they are the only directive in this template.

But the above code does not lead to a rendering of all tags within the template. It always stops rendering after the first directive was rendered. Even the not-directive tag `<span>` is not being rendered.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the browser console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current Angular version requires proper HTML

`<audio-controls>` and `<track-display>` should be `<audio-controls></audio-controls>` and `<track-display></track-display>`

maybe there are other issues, but your question doesn't contain enough information (code) to be able to tell.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. :)